# Divide numbers in SQL

Tags: sql

I have a database with orders of products and i need to divide the orders for men with the all orders for every year.

I successfully printed the all orders for every year and the mens orders for every year but I don't have an idea how to show a number that divide the numbers.

```
SELECT 
    YEAR(o.Order_Date) AS year,
    COUNT(o.order_id) AS number_of_orders
FROM
    [targil 2].[dbo].[exc2 - product] p, [targil 2].[dbo].[exc2 - orders] o
WHERE 
    p.Product_ID = o.Product_ID 
GROUP BY
    YEAR(o.Order_Date);
```

Output =

```
   year    number_of_orders
   -------------------------
   2012        540
   2013        512
   2014        180

SELECT DISTCINT
    YEAR(o.Order_Date) AS year, 
    COUNT(o.order_id) AS number_of_orders
FROM
    [targil 2].[dbo].[exc2 - product] p, [targil 2].[dbo].[exc2 - orders] o
WHERE 
    p.Product_ID = o.Product_ID 
    AND p.Product_Name LIKE '%men%'
GROUP BY
    YEAR(o.Order_Date);
```

Output

```
year  number_of_orders
----------------------
2012       50
2013      146
2014      138
```

Desired output

```
year   number_of_men_orders_of_all_orders
----------------------------------------
2012        0.0925
2013        0.285
2014        0.766
```

Comment: If you create a SQL Fiddle with some dummy data and desired output you'll be more likely to get an answer.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation!  And learn to use proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax

```
select year(o.Order_Date) as year,
       count(*) as number_of_orders,
       sum(case when p.Product_Name LIKE '%men%' then 1 else 0 end) as men_count,
       avg(case when p.Product_Name LIKE '%men%' then 1.0 else 0 end) as men_ratio,
from [targil 2].[dbo].[exc2 - product] p join
     [targil 2].[dbo].[exc2 - orders] o
      on p.Product_ID = o.Product_ID 
group by year(o.Order_Date)
order by year(o.Order_date);
```

Comment: @user1986315 . . . I'm surprised that you prefer the more complicated, less performant solution.

Answer (score 1):

What flavor of SQL are you using? It looks like MS Sql Server.

You will have to join your two result sets on their year so you can compare the count of each. Try something like this:

```
WITH all_orders AS (
    SELECT YEAR(Order_Date) 'Year', COUNT(*) 'Count'
    FROM [targil 2].[dbo].[exc2 - orders]
    GROUP BY YEAR(Order_Date)
), men_orders AS (
    SELECT YEAR(o.Order_Date) 'Year', COUNT(*) 'Count'
    FROM [targil 2].[dbo].[exc2 - orders] o
    JOIN [targil 2].[dbo].[exc2 - product] p
        ON p.Product_ID = o.Product_ID
    WHERE p.Product_Name LIKE '%men%'
    GROUP BY YEAR(o.Order_Date)
)
SELECT
    COALESCE(a.Year, m.Year) 'Year',
    a.Count 'All Count',
    m.Count 'Men Count',
    CAST(ISNULL(m.Count, 0) AS DECIMAL) / CAST(a.Count AS DECIMAL) 'Ratio'
FROM all_orders a
LEFT JOIN men_orders m ON m.Year = a.Year
```

Comment: @Neil . . . This is much more complicated and inefficient than it needs to be.

Comment: @GordonLinoff thanks your answer is much simpler, I hadn't considered using `avg` like that.